# PayPal Merchant SDK returning invalid XML

Tags: c#, .net, paypal

Using PayPalMerchantSDK v2.14.117.0.

Requesting transaction details.

Getting an XML parser error about 80% of the time.

Just started happening a few weeks ago. No changes to my code.

```
at System.Xml.XmlDocument.LoadXml(String xml)
at PayPal.PayPalAPIInterfaceService.PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService.GetTransactionDetails(GetTransactionDetailsReq getTransactionDetailsReq, String apiUserName)
```

Clean response looks like:

```
<ScheduledShippingPeriod xsi:type="xs:string">
</ScheduledShippingPeriod>
```

Dirty:

```
<ScheduledShippingPeriod xsi:type="xs:string">�7�
</ScheduledShippingPeriod>
```

**' ', hexadecimal value 0x13, is an invalid character. Line 1, position 7759.**

Note the invalid characters. Both the clean and dirty response was for the same transactions.

The problem appears to be in the PayPal API when it returns invalid XML.
Has anyone encountered anything like this? I've googled but no luck. 
Is there someone I can call at PayPal to discuss this?

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this on Sandbox?  If you'd like to contact PayPal directly, you can do so through the [PayPal Merchant Technical Support](https://ppmts.custhelp.com/) site.

Comment: Also, you may want to replace the `paypal-rest-sdk` tag with the `paypalmerchantsdk` tag since this is regarding the Classic API and not REST. :)

Comment: @Jazon Z I haven't tested this behaviour in the sandbox. It appears in the live environment but only for some transactions. Some are un-affected. Those that are affected only exhibit this behaviour about 80% of the time. What we've been doing is re-trying until it works. Takes about 4-5 tries.

Answer (score 0):

0x13 is ASCII for CR. Strip out \r from your XML string and see if that fixes your issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, the XML is loaded and parsed inside the SDK so I have no access to the XML to parse out anything. Also, the invalid character seems to change. Sometimes it's 0x16 and 0x17